# php - TRUE or true difference?

Tags: php

I'm wondering, in PHP, I've seen people use both these cases:

```
if($var === TRUE)

if($var === true)
```

is there an actual difference between them or a coding standard/format to be used in boolean value?

Comment: No difference. If you want to follow the [PSR-2 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md), they must be in lower case.

Comment: What about _True_ and _False_? I've seen that being used and strangely the code was supposed to work, but I doubt it...

Comment: Guess, it's related with getting used to another language before becoming a PHP developer. For example in python docs, it says `True` and `False`, while in C++ you define `TRUE` and `FALSE` as constants assigned to 1 and 0 (if you don't already use `stdbool.h` and obey the "constants should be uppercase" rule).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There's no difference at all. From [the docs](http://php.net/language.types.boolean):

> To specify a boolean literal, use the keywords TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.

[According to PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#25-keywords-and-truefalsenull), as stated by both Laxus and Paul Bain in their comments, the *standard* is to write them in lower case.

Comment: for Developers who will read this in 2020year :)
PSR-2 is deprecated now you can read PSR-12 2.5 https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/

Answer (score 12):

lowercase is generally considered a good practice, see the coloration of the lowercase on stackoverflow :)

And not related, but you should always use true first in the condition `true === $var`, this is a good practice to avoid sneaky bugs when mistyping the condition, eg : `$var = true`